# allow user to enter checkbox text via xml or code

Tags: android

I have an activity with four checkboxes in it in a typical quiz format. I am trying to allow user to to edit the question(check box text) and check the check boxes he/she wishes to. Any suggestions on how to do this?

one of my four checkboxes are currently like this

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable="true"
    android:text="type answer 1 here. Select check box if this is the right answer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your Question right. You want to let the user change the Label of the Checkbox during runtime, right?

For this case I would suggest to add entry methods (for example TextViews) to an "edit" form and set the corresponding checkbox's text via checkbox.setText().

I hope this is an answer which helps you.

Comment: Yes, you got the question right. I guess there is no way to have an edit option. The way you have suggested is what I will need to do I think.